# Product image does not display correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image-preview

Somehow the product image of our shop does not display correctly, normally the image is enlarged when you mouse over it, somehow only the top left enlarges and there is no way to look at the rest of the image.

If you look at this shop: [**www.jo-l-fashion.com**](http://www.jo-l-fashion.com) and select any product (for instance 'tassen' and then any item. The item is displayed in the main window, when you mouse over it only the top enlarges.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have found jQuery errors on your site. Try to add noConflict()

Create file:

> /js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js

With following:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then attach this file to every page of your site.

To the file base/default/layout/local.xml

add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Don't forget to check that your file was successfully attached. (find it on your live)

**upd.1**

Ok, let me explain what has happening on your site. When you open your page with your zoomer or any other javascript which use jQuery library you get error like:

> TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function

**Why does it issue happen?** Magento has native javascript library **prototype.js**. But most of modern modules do not use this library, because it's not popular in our days. They use **jQuery** library. Why do issues appear? If you want to select some element with id="element"

Prototype: `$('element')`

jQuery: `$('#element')`

And when you execute any script on your page magento don't know which library to use. That because you need to redeclare '$'  symbol. When you execute `jQuery.noConflict()` function magento start use for jQuery another symbol and selector for id="element" will be:

`jQuery('#element')`

You can read for more details: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

**If you still have any question - feel free to ask.**

Comment: Forgive me for being a noob (to use a popular word) but how do I attach a file to a page?

Comment: Via layout. I also wrote that above.

Comment: The moment I add the new header to the xml file I get the 'fresh' install screen of magento. In the background I get the error message 'Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Entity: line 36: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/httpd/vhosts/jo-l-fashion.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 766'

Comment: jQuery is not native javascript library in magento, that because you need to let it exist with native library prototype. Make it how I recommended

Comment: I tried to recreate your instructions. 1. I created the noconflict.js file with the code (jQue...();) you gave. 2. I added the code (<?xml...out>) to the local.xml file. 3. In the magento backend I go to General/Design where I click Layout. In here I have to give a matched expression and a value. Could you guide me through this please?

Comment: You don't need to change anything in admin area. You need to apply this script on every page on frontend. That because you need to use handle <default>, as I noticed above. I don't clearly understand what did you mean in point 3.

Comment: It seems my two questions (this one and my question regarding the menu bar) are the same problem, somewhere there is a jQuery/Superfish error. I will try to find out more about this problem, no idea how to solve ith though.

Comment: I have updated my post. If you have any question - just ask.

Comment: Slowly I start to understand what's happening @zhartaunik but my knowledge of programming is limited. <br> I managed to create the noconfilict file, next you want me to edit a local.xml file, there is no /base folder in the root of the webshop, I found two /base folders, one in /app/etc and in /errors. Which file do I need to edit?<br>After that you want me to check if the file is successfully added, how do I do that?<br>Thanks in advance for your patience and help!

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/default/layout create here local.xml

Comment: Ok, I followed your instructions but sadly no result. I still don't quite understand how to attach a file to every page, forgive me for being dumb but could you explain that a little more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open any page on your site and view source code. Try to find there this noconflict.js file. p.s. don't you forget to create it? Do you use merge scripts? Disable it for a while

Comment: When I search the source code's I see the noconflict, right after the slider.css. Is there a possibility to overwrite the page which displays the product? Perhaps you could send me that page?

Comment: I managed to remove the whole scaling option from Magento which solves the problem (better no scaling then wrong scaling) Thanks all for your remarks!